# How To Measure Contrast in OpenCV + Visual C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

The question was previously "How to select image of best contrast in OpenCV" but as per @Rook's suggestion, I'm changing it.

I am going to use OpenCV + Visual Studio 2010 on my project. I just wanna know how OpenCV can make this easier for me. I have extracted around a thousand frames from a video and I need to find out which one has the best contrast. By best, I think the quality between the highest and the lowest contrast.

I have been searching the web for reference codes but so far, I haven't found one.

UPDATE: So basically, I need to measure the contrast and compare values between the images. By the way, this is a video of a Mars Observation via a telescope and I'm gonna be using the frames extracted from it.

Comment: Until you can quantify what "best contrast" actually means, there's no way for you to make this selection. _"the quality between the highest and the lowest contrast."_ doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think the word would be 'midpoint(?)' between the highest and lowest value. Thanks

Comment: So your question is actually, "how can I compute the contrast of an image?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entropy of image is used as a measure of contrast. See this [code](http://areshopencv.blogspot.ru/2011/12/computing-entropy-of-image.html).

> Entropy is a scalar value, statistical measure of randomness that can be used to characterize the texture of the input image. Entropy is defined as
>
> ```
> -sum(p.*log2(p))
> ```
>
> where `p` contains the histogram counts.

— [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html)